# What are the projective and the injective objects in the category of spectra?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy-theory

> What are the projective and the injective objects in the category of spectra (of simplicial sets)?
>   Does the category of spectra have enough projectives and injectives?

An object $P$ of a category $C$ is called [projective](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/projective+object), if $\operatorname{hom}_C(P,-)$ preserves epimorphisms.

An object $I$ of a category $C$ is called [injective](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/injective+object), if $\operatorname{hom}_C(-,I)$ takes monomorphisms to epimorphisms.

The *category of spectra* (of simplicial sets) in question has as objects $X$ sequences of pointed simplicial sets $X_0, X_1,X_2,\ldots$ together with (pointed) structure maps $\Sigma X_n\to X_{n+1}$ and as morphisms $X\to Y$ sequences of morphisms $X_n\to Y_n$ of pointed simplicial sets making the obvious diagram involving the structure maps commute.

Comment: I don't like calling this "the category of spectra." Spectra naturally form an $\infty$-category, not a category. There are *model* categories of spectra which present this $\infty$-category, and there is a homotopy category of spectra. Whatever this is, it doesn't yet have enough data attached to it to even count as a presentation of the $\infty$-category of spectra.

Comment: Dear Qiaochu Yuan, I am sorry for the probably badly-chosen name. Anyway, I neither want to consider the stable homotopy category (as a triangulated category, all its objects are injective and projective) nor the $\infty$-category of spectra, I am talking about an ordinary 1-category.

Comment: There should be plenty of projectives, as with any other category of essentially algebraic structures.